# Div height 100% not going along with bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This plain code(btw, I took it from another stackoverflow poste) works as the red **div#wrapper** reaches from top to bottom...

```
<html>
<head>
<style media="screen">
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
#first {
    background-color:#F5DEB3;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="first"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I integrate this to a wordpress+bootstrap+timber theme it's not working... even with a `html,body{height: 100% }` written in **style.css**...

I'm not sure if this is bootstrap or wordpress related problem...

```
hmtl, body{
    height: 100%!important;
}

#wrapper {
    height:100%!important;
    background-color:red;
}

.navbar-brand-image{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        text-align: center
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}



.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px
}

.navbar .navbar-nav a{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold
}

.navbar .navbar-nav a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is the Bootstrap/WP  CSS overriding this?You'll have to open console and check.

Comment: I can have my console to check... I'm primarily using Inspect Element on firefox... I just don't know where to find... :) :(

Comment: try important keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the CSS in the page it's not possible to pinpoint the problem.  You can however add an !important to the height element to ignore any CSS inheritance.

```
#wrapper {
    height:100% !important;
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: but *!important* is a bad use

Answer (score 0):

When you use these libraries there are big chances of them override in your code.

To check if this is the case place **`!important`**  at the end of your css properties.

Example:

```
#wrapper {
    height:100% !important;
    width:300px !important;
    background-color:red !important;
}
```